# How do I get play-doh out of the carpet?

Tags: toys, cleaning

We've introduced our son to [Play-Doh](http://www.hasbro.com/playdoh/en_us/), and he loves it.

However, he's still only 2, and is not very good about watching where the stuff goes.  He drops a lot of it, and then winds up stepping on it.

We've wound up with some of it ground into our carpet.  What's the best way to clean up the mess?

Comment: Oh - good luck there @Beofett...my brother went for wooden floors for this exact reason:-)

Comment: Fortunately we do have wooden floors, and not wall-to-wall carpeting, so the carpet that now has a techni-colored mess embedded in it is easily replaceable :)

Comment: I am glad your child loves Play-Doh.  Mine asks daddy to open the Play-Doh so that he can take Play-Doh and place it on the carpet while he happily goes on playing with the empty container.  +1 since I have the same need.

Comment: I can also attest to this method. A washcloth, dish soap, cold water and a carpet brush. Wait a few minutes and it comes right out!

Comment: Play-Doh is made up of some simple ingredients. Flour, salt, oil and water. Consider that if you choose to use water to get it out. Water may cause the dyes in the dough to transfer to the carpet. That's probably why the dry method works better, or so I'm told. Our carpet is too dark to notice if the dyes are transferring, and we haven't really had to get out packed in dough before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I decided to go and hunt down an answer for this because although so far we have managed to keep playdough in the kitchen, which has a wooden floor, it is bound to happen sometime.

So, the official line from Hasbro is:

> “When attempting to remove PLAY-DOH compound do NOT use hot water or
>   cleaning solutions of any kind. To remove PLAY-DOH compound from
>   carpet or fabrics, allow it to dry completely, and then loosen with a
>   stiff brush. It may be necessary to vacuum clean or wash with gentle
>   soap and cold water.  You may need to repeat the process in order to
>   completely remove the PLAY-DOH compound.”

Amusingly, the first source of that guidance, which quoted Hasbros own information was a blog called [Playdoughinmycarpet](http://www.playdoughinmycarpet.com/playdough-facts/)

Comment: I can attest to the success of this method!

Comment: Put ice packs on the area first.